# NullPointerException after starting activity from onClickListener inside RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm getting the following error in logcat after calling `startActivity` from `onClickListener` inside a `RecyclerView` in a `Fragment`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:861)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:602)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
```

This happens after the other activity has been created (`OnCreate` called)

Here's the `Fragment`'s `onViewCreated`:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View view = getView();
    RecyclerView list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    list.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getResources()));

    //Tried commenting out three of the following lines, no effect
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    list.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    ArrayList<TimelineItem> timelineItems = new ArrayList<>();
    //populating the list with dummy data

    adapter = new TimelineAdapter(timelineItems);
    //this sets the onclick listener on the view inside the ViewHolder
    adapter.setPrimaryClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openProfile();
        }
    });

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Code for `openProfile`:

```
public void openProfile(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfileActivity.class);
    //NPE happens after this
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Adapter code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TimelineAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    TimelineItem timelineItem = dataSet.get(i);

    //bunch of findViewById

    secondaryAction.setOnClickListener(secondaryClickListener);
    textContent.setOnClickListener(primaryClickListener);
    avatar.setOnClickListener(primaryClickListener);
}
```

Turns out that this error always happens when switching to a new activity. Not specific to this `OnClickListener`

Comment: Please comment beside the line where you getting the NPE

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fragment wasnt attached to the activity yet, so getActivity() returns null. When dealing with fragments, its good to override the `onAttach()` and get the instance of the activity from there, to make sure the fragment is attached.

Answer (score 0):

> onBindViewHolder (VH holder, int position)
>   Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position. This method should update the contents of the itemView to reflect the item at the given position.
>   Blockquote

Perhaps you are missing `super.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, i)`?

Comment: `super.onBindViewHolder` is abstract and cannot be called

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, turns out I was using version 21 of `v7-recyclerview` , updating it to 22 solved this